# Question on solution for 2013 USAJMO #1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem and solution can be viewed [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2013_USAJMO_Problems/Problem_1)

My question is on the part where they state

> If $a^5b\equiv 6\pmod 9$, then note that $3|b$. This is because if
>   $3|a$ then $a^5b\equiv 0\pmod 9$.

I don't understand how they got that b is divisible by 3. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $a^5b \equiv 6\pmod 9$ we have that $3 | a^5b$. So it must be true that either $3 | a$ or $3 |b$. But $3$ cannot divide $a$ for if it does then $9 | a^5$ and therefore $9 | a^5b$ which contradicts $a^5b \equiv 6\pmod 9$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\equiv 6\pmod 9$, then $3\,|\,x$.  Now, $3\not |\,a$ because if so, then $a=3y$ and $a^5=3^5y^5=3\cdot 9^2y^5$ and $a^5b\equiv 0\pmod 9$, which is not the case. Therefore, $3\,|\,b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is a multiple of 3, then $a^2$ is a multiple of 9, and $a^2 \times a^3\times b$ is a multiple of 9. This contradicts the fact that $a^5b\equiv 6\pmod 9$.